# C++ Initializing Array of Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, array-initialization

I know with pointers you can do this:

```
T * myPtr = 0;
```

which sets the pointer to a NULL value. However, when I try to do this:

```
T * myPtrArray[2] = {0, 0};
```

I get the "expected expression" syntax error. Why?

Note, I'm using g++ and the code above occurs in a class constructor:

```
template <class T>
    RBTree<T>::RBTree() {
        m_Data = T();
        m_Children = {0, 0};
        m_Parent = 0;
        m_Color = BLACK;
    }
```

where the class members in question are declared as:

```
T m_Data;
RBTree<T> * m_Children[2];
RBTree<T> * m_Parent;
bool m_Color;
```

Comment: What compiler? Works for me with g++, clang and msvc.

Comment: It should work. Any context?

Comment: Please show the actual error message.

Comment: That's assignment, not initialization. There's a difference. Arrays don't support assignment.

Comment: I thought that because it's in the constructor it would be considered initialization. Is this wrong then?

Comment: @Woody1193: It's initialization if it's in the _initializer list_ of the constructor. See suggestion #1 of yzn-pku's answer. The body of a constructor are just regular statements.

Comment: Where do you declare and initialize this array? Is this a class member or somwhere within a method?

Comment: General advice: It is usually good to avoid C arrays and naked pointers. Use std::vector and a suitable smart pointer instead (swiss knife: std::shared_ptr, more specific/clear usage: std::unique_ptr).

Comment: @bkausbk It is a class member and it was assignment, not initialization. I was mistaken in my belief that construction would count for initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form `T * myPtrArray[2] = {0, 0};` is called [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). It has no counterpart in assignment, so writing

```
T * myPtrArray[2];
myPtrArray = {0, 0};
```

is invalid.

In the case of class construction, aggregate initialization is unavailable in c++98/03.

If your compiler supports c++11 standard, you can use uniform initialization syntax. There are two ways to initialize `m_Children` in your example:

#### #1

In constructor:

```
template <class T>
RBTree<T>::RBTree(): m_Children {0, 0} /* other init here */ {

}
```

#### #2

During class member declaration:

```
T m_Data;
RBTree<T> * m_Children[2] {0, 0};
RBTree<T> * m_Parent;
bool m_Color;
```

Comment: #1 isn't supported pre-C++11. But `m_children()` is, and is probably the better option because ti does not depend on the number of elements in the array.

Comment: ITYM #2 isn't supported (during class member declaration).

Answer (score 0):

As of C++11, you can use `nullptr` instead of `0`. Using `nullptr` is preferred, as it is a pointer instead of an integer. Then, you could do:

```
T * myPtrArray[2] = {nullptr, nullptr};
```

Anyway, your code works fine on my compiler, you can see an example using both `0` and `nullptr` that compiles without errors [on ideone](http://ideone.com/ePRc7w).